# Google Sheets - Dropdown filter

Tags: filter, google-sheets, dropdown

I want to have an in-cell dropdown list that can filter content in a Google Sheet. For example:

```
Name | Info | Category ▼
------------------------
Bob  | Lorem| A
------------------------
Alice| Ipsum| B
------------------------
```

What I want to achieve: when I click the triangle, a dropdown appears with options A and B, and if I select A, the content of the sheet is filtered so that I am only seeing the row with Bob.

I also want to do this in place (I was trying with QUERY but I couldn't find a way to output the result in place).

Comment: Little more clarity is needed. Can't you try this with filter views?  Query will output the whole row but you need different sheet or some other place to view it. It won't filter the original data.

Comment: You are right about QUERY and afaik I don't think it'd work in the case. Filter view would produce similar results, but I wanted to filter content after selecting an option in an in-cell dropdown list. I think having a dropdown is just more intuitive. And if a dropdown can dynamically filter content, other people don't have to create their filter views.